# How to avoid overwriting of data in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code for adding records in Firebase. there's variable outside called restauCount valued (int) as 1

```
public void sendMessage(){

    int restauCount = 1;
    String identifier ="Restaurant" + restauCount;
    Firebase userRef = firebaseRef.child("Caloocan");
    EditText nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    String name = nameInput.getText().toString();

    EditText locInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
    String location = locInput.getText().toString();

    EditText typeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeTxt);
    String foodtype = typeInput.getText().toString();
    if (!name.equals("")){
        Map<String, String> caloocan = new HashMap<String, String>();
        caloocan.put("resname", name);
        caloocan.put("resloc", location);
        caloocan.put("foodtype", foodtype);

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> users = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        users.put(identifier,caloocan);

        userRef.setValue(users);
        restauCount++;
    }
}
```

When i run the sendessage() again. i will type in the fields and when i click ADD which is the sendMessage it will be added in FireBase , however when i add new data. IT OVERWRITES THE OLD DATA INPUTTED ? HOW CAN I ADD MULTIPLE DATA IN FIREBASE WITHOUT OVERWRITING THE DATA? 
restauCount was created to increment the number of Restaurant i inputted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update the `identifier` it stays the same :

```
int restauCount = 1;
String identifier ="Restaurant" + restauCount;
```

try something like :

```
    long restauCount = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String identifier ="Restaurant" + restauCount;
```

here each time you send a `sendMessage()` your identifier got a specific id as the current time in milliseconds + "Restaurant"

if its important to keep int numbers let me know

Comment: the error of my code was in the .put() not in my counter for restau, sorry

Comment: have you tried my answer?, because to avoid OVERWRITING the data you need each time a new identifier

Comment: it works, but i need a unique ID to easily retrieve data if i will be using it. any idea? like counter that will increment  when i press the button ?

Comment: thanks for the idea bro. problem solved. created int for the entire class instead of time! :)

Comment: glad to help Allen

Answer (score 2):

`userRef.push().setValue(users);`
The push() method generates a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
userRef.setValue(users).push();
```

instead of  `userRef.setValue(users);`

Comment: there's an error with push. my app closes when i tried putting this "userRef.setValue(userRef.push());"

Comment: its not userRef.setValue(userRef.push()); 
it is userRef.setValue(users).push();

Answer (score 1):

You are using always the **same ref**

```
String identifier ="Restaurant" + restauCount;
Firebase userRef = firebaseRef.child("Caloocan");
userRef.setValue(users);
restauCount++;
```

[Check the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write):

> Using setValue() in this way overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes.

In your case you **are overriding the same data** for this reason.

You should use the `push()` method to generate a unique ID every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.

```
Firebase userRef = firebaseRef.child("Caloocan");
Firebase newRef =  userRef.push();
newRef.setValue(users);

//to get the key
String key = newRef.getKey();
```